# How to extract path after IP address?

Tags: c#, regex

The example IP address looks like:

> ftp:// 192.168.1.1/dir1/dir2/file.txt

How can I extract:

1. dir1/dir2/file.txt
2. dir1/dir2/

with regular expression.

I have following regular expression.

```
Regex ip = new Regex(@"((ftp://)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})");
string []m = ip.Split(ftpAddress);
```

Comment: why can't you use `new Uri("ftp:// 192.168.1.1/dir1/dir2/file.txt").PathAndQuery` instead?

Comment: Oh thanks Mathew... It solved my problem. You can put this solution to answer so that I can mark it as solution

Comment: But anyways, how can we do it through regex,,, I have spend too much time struggling with regex, so I would like to know a proper regex solution too. Thanks

Comment: Why does everyone want to use regex for everything these days?

Comment: @Irfan Regex isn't the solution to everything...

Comment: @Default where text parsing is concerned, regex is a solution to everything. It just isn't always _the_ solution. Expecially in c# where Microsoft have often done it for you (in this case, with the Uri class). It probably uses regex under the covers. Don't reinvent the wheel, but I admire Irfan for wanting to know the regex solution anyway.

Comment: It depends on how crucial your parsing is. If its just a single parse then it does not really matter if you use regex. Ultimately regex is fast but not always the easiest / best readable solution. maybe its one of those personal preference things.

Comment: @Gusdor well said. I may have formulated myself bad - I mean that, when looking to solve a programming problem in C#, regex would seldom be my first choice.

Comment: @NicolasTyler Different strokes for different folks I think. I find regex very maintainable and find lots of splits and linq expressions harder to read. Arguably, you pay in performance with regex but I've yet to suffer from it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ftpAddress = "ftp://192.168.1.1/dir1/dir2/file.txt";
Regex ip = new Regex(@"ftp://\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}");
string path1 = ip.Split(ftpAddress)[1];
string path2 = new Uri(ftpAddress).PathAndQuery;
string path3 = ftpAddress.Substring(ftpAddress.IndexOf("/", 6));
```